# Animate each row insertion separately Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation, custom-cell

Im inserting new section (`insertSections`) as well as new rows inside it (`insertRowsAtIndexPaths`). I'm using those two functions for the sake of `withRowAnimation` parameter.

With the help of stack community i've been able to override the in-built animation and make it longer - with the following trick in the `cellForRowAtIndexPaths`

```
    if(storedarraysofindexes[indexPath.section].containsIndex(indexPath.row)){
        //for _ in storedarraysofindexes[indexPath.section]{

        for _ in storedarraysofindexes[indexPath.section]{
            cell.alpha = 0

        UIView.animateWithDuration(4.0, animations:  {() in
            cell.alpha = 1.0
            }, completion:{(Bool)  in
            self.storedarraysofindexes[indexPath.section].removeIndex(indexPath.row)
        })}}
```

i'm saving every indexPath.row for every section into an array of `NSMutableIndexSets` and removing it after the effect was applied.

Animation works, but all of the cells are inserted at once. I want this animation to apply for every new inserted cell separately. Unfortunately, even for loop (mentioned in the code) didn't help me to solve this issue.

Any insights are greatly appreciated.

UPDATE

Added the code for insertRowsAtIndexPaths and insertSections wrapped in a function

```
func insertData(){

// step 1 - appending the array

my2darray.append(dataarray[option1]!)


// step 2 -generating a range of IndexPaths for the appended array values

     let insertedIndexPathRange = 0..<self.dataarray[self.option1]!.count + 1
     self.insertedIndexPaths = insertedIndexPathRange.map { NSIndexPath(forRow: $0, inSection: self.my2darray.count - 1) }



// step 3 - appending our NSMutableIndexSet with current indexes

     var update2 = NSMutableIndexSet ()

    for indexPathMe in insertedIndexPathRange{
        update2.addIndex(indexPathMe)
    }
    storedarraysofindexes += [update2]

// step 4 - inserting sections as well as rows

    self.tableView1.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView1.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: self.my2darray.count - 1), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    self.tableView1.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(insertedIndexPaths, withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    self.tableView1.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: Looks like you add another code, most of the methods (insertSection,InsertRwoAtIndex,....)you talked about, are not in the code.

Comment: @Iman sure, i'll add the code for insertRows and sections in a moment

Comment: @Iman just added the codes